# This is regarding Android Applinks / Deeplinks issue from outlook-email

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, applinks

In our Hybrid Mobile(ionic-V3) application Applinks/Deeplinks is working fine from email clients such as gmail, yahoo etc. Where-in on click of the link we are getting the “disambiguation dialog / app chooser” to select the application to open the link.

But when we click on the same link from outlook-email it is directly opening in the browser , as any external links in Outlook e-mail route through safe links which in turn not allowing to do the deep linking to the APP.

Request you all to please let us know if any one came across the same issue and found solution.

Comment: Haven't tried personally, but maybe try to set up a redirect page that opens the deep link? so instead of opening it directly from the mail client, the link in the mail sends you to a page that opens your app on its turn?

Comment: We have a use case that when the user opens the link in the browser we are taking him to another page :(. So if we do this redirection that this usecase will break.